# swift append new column to array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, append

I want to organize a multidimensional array by rows. 
I have a function that created 3 arrays from one main array. I want to add these subarrays to a new array in the form of columns ideally.

I tried the following:

```
/* Note

-subArray is a data structure where i have 3 values stored at each 
index index. these are named data1, data2, data3. I'm accessing them 
with the line chamberOne.append(thing.data1). this is referenced 
from tempCount's data. 

- data structure: 
at index # 1
 -data1
 -data1
 -data3

*/


static func subArray()->[String]
{
   var temp = mainArray[0...11]
   let tempCount = Array(temp)
   var returnArr: [String] = []

   var chamberOne: [String] = []
   for thing in tempCount
   {
      chamberOne.append(thing.data1)
   }
   // i have 2 more functions built the same as chamberOne, but they 
   //are named chamberTwo and chamberThree

   //as of right now I am appending like this
   returnArr + chamberOne + chamberTwo + chamberThree
  // this brings all the data into a single dimension array. 
}
```

I want a way to append `chamberOne`,`chamberTwo`, and `chamberThree` as columns OR rows, either would be fine, I just want some form of organization into a multidimensional space via appending a 1d array (`chamberOne`) to a multidimensional array (`returnArr`).

Comment: Are the chambers the same `length` or could be any length?

Comment: all the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose you have two arrays like:

```
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
var arr2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Now we create an array that will hold other arrays like:

```
var multiDimArray = [[String]]() //Array of subarrays
```

We can now add both arrays to `multiDimArray`

```
multiDimArray.append(arr1)
multiDimArray.append(arr2)
```

If we print `multiDimArray` we get `[["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]]`

If we need first "row" we can get it with `multiDimArray[0]` which gets us `["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: this is actually append row not append "column"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need a `[[String]]` aka `Array of Arrays of String`. Here's how I would modify your function to account for that:

```
static func subArray() -> [[String]]
{
   var temp = mainArray[0...11]
   let tempCount = Array(temp)
   var returnArr: [[String]] = []

   var chamberOne: [String] = []

   for thing in tempCount
   {
      chamberOne.append(thing.data1)
   }

   returnArr.append(chamberOne)

   //Initialise chamberTwo and chamberThree here. Then append to the 2D array.
   returnArr.append(chamberTwo)
   returnArr.append(chamberThree)

   //The returnArr now looks like this [chamberOne, chamberTwo, chamberThree]
   returnArr
}
```